# Converting all NoneType objects returned from SQL query into strings?

Tags: python, sql

Is there a way to convert all NoneType objects returned from an SQL query to empty strings? Right now I'm doing

```
curs.execute(query)
for foo, bar, baz in curs.fetchall():
    foo = foo or ''
    bar = bar or ''
    baz = baz or ''
```

but I'm sure there's a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
new_list = [ ('' if x is None else x) for x in curs.fetchall() ]
```